# Problem with the permissions of newly created /tmp

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems, python, dynamic-linking

On an Ubuntu 14.04 system I had to enlarge the /tmp folder, and instead of resizing partitions I unmounted the partition mounted to /tmp and created a new file mounted to /tmp, following the instructions [here](https://www.vps.net/community/knowledgebase/display/vpsfeatures/How+to+increase+tmp+partition+size).

I changed the permissions to this new /tmp folder to 1777, but I get some permissions issue - when I compile some c++/cuda code from Python (using Codepy, creating a shared object), I get the following error when (within the compilation code) the shared object is loaded (compilation is done into subfolder of /tmp):

> failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

I have a similar machine (it was a clone) where this does not happen, so I guess it has something to do with the /tmp folder.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the `noexec` if you copied that from the guide, that is an unusual setting for `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guide is not the best to follow.

Instead, mount your `/tmp` as `tmpfs` and reap the benefits of much faster compiling, and faster `/tmp` usage for other things.

`tmpfs` is an in-memory filesystem which is very well suited for `/tmp` usage.

It also reduces hard drive writes which can be a bit useful for the paranoid folks who don't want to write to their SSDs often.

To accomplsih this, unmount `/tmp` and undo everything you did that guide.

```
mount -t tmpfs temp /tmp -o size=4G,nosuid,nodev
```

Note that `size=4G` can and should be changed depending on how much memory your system has. I use 1/4th of my total system memory. You can check with the command `free` for memory total and usages.

Note that the 3rd argument, `temp` in the command above can actually be anything you want. Make it something more descriptive if you want, but it must be a single argument so if you use spaces, encase it in quotes.

Comment: Thanks - does that mean the available RAM will be smaller? This is a workstation with 4 GPU's and quite a heavy workload so every GB counts (64GB at the moment)

Comment: It means that the size of the contents of `/tmp` will be subtracted from current free memory. If memory is required for other uses, the contents of `/tmp` will instead utilize the virtual memory (swap). From my experience, when workloads are heavily I/O bound, this significantly increases throughput. Beware that an unexpected shutdown will cause a complete loss of `/tmp` contents. If you're using a UPS, it isn't a problem.

Comment: I'll add that the kernel will dynamically free the memory used by a `tmpfs` mountpoint. So the `size=` option only defines a maximum limit, not an allocation.

Comment: One last thing - can/should I add this mount to /etc/fstab?

Comment: Yes, that's the typical thing to do. (15 character comment limit)